# Python 'print' isn't working in Catalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

What I typed and what I got:

```
>>> print 'hello world'
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'geoprocessing sys.stdout object' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Any suggestions? I have tried restarting to no effect, should I just go straight to re-installing? I am using ArcCatalog 10.4.1

Comment: From the command line enter 'where python' and 'python --version' . Include the results to your post.

Comment: I just tested your simple code in my ArcCatalog and it ran as expected. I think you have a corrupted install of python, maybe caused by different versions. I would do as you suggested just go for a reinstall.

Comment: I think Hornbydd is right, it works fine in mine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing Arc solved the problem